# What's wrong in this design that causes infinite loop?

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, infinite-loop

I will explain myself by giving you a descriptive example. Let's say I'm programming a very simple Cloud Storage Simulation, a simple terminal program. I have two main classes, User and File coded as follows:

```
class User {
       Set<File> sharedFiles;
       void shareFile(File f){
           sharedFiles.add(f);
           f.shareWith(this);
       }
}

class File {
       Set<User> sharedUsers;
       void shareWith(User u){
           sharedUsers.add(u);
           u.shareFile(this);
       }
}
```

I pretend to have access to the files that have been shared to an user, and to the users that a file has been shared to, so I code the lists `sharedFiles` and `sharedUsers`.

Then, I do:

```
main(){
    User u = new User();
    File f = new File();
    u.shareFile(f); // or f.shareWith(u), doesn't matter
}
```

I know it is a pretty obvious case of infinite loop. In fact, this code causes `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError`. Both methods keep calling each other indefinitely.

So, in your opinion, What would be the ideal solution for this problem and a **good design** for this two classes?

Comment: Both methods keep calling each other indefinitely.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a check whether a object of one class already holds a reference to the object of the other class before calling the `shareWith` method:

```
class User {
       Set<File> sharedFiles;
       boolean hasFile (File f) {
           return sharedFiles.contains(f);
       }
       void shareFile(File f){
           sharedFiles.add(f);
           if (!f.hasUser(this))
               f.shareWith(this);
       }
}

class File {
       Set<User> sharedUsers;
       boolean hasUser (User u) {
           return sharedUsers.contains(u);
       }
       void shareWith(User u){
           sharedUsers.add(u);
           if (!u.hasFile(this))
               u.shareFile(this);
       }
}
```

EDIT: of course this code is missing the initialization of the `sharedUsers` and `sharedFiles` sets, but I'm assuming you have that initialization in your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling, on "this" its keep on calling your method infinite time

```
class File {
   Set<User> sharedUsers;
   void shareWith(User u){
       sharedUsers.add(u);
       u.shareFile(this);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2 functions (shareFile and shareWith) simply call eacher again and again. You either need to add some checking, whether the set already contains the element and return, or do something like this...

```
class User {
   Set<File> sharedFiles;
   void shareFile(File f){
       sharedFiles.add(f);
   }


class File {
   Set<User> sharedUsers;
   void shareWith(User u){
       sharedUsers.add(u);
   }
}

main(){
   User u = new User();
   File f = new File();
   u.shareFile(f);
   f.shareWith(u);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For better design, you should not have a cyclic dependency like this at all.

The user is not dependent on the files he shares.

The file is not dependent on the users it is shared with.

Consider something like this:

```
class User {
    String firstName, lastName; // or something
}
class File {
    String filename, path; // or something
}

class Sharestorage {
    Map<User,Set<File>> userToFiles = new HashMap<>();
    Map<File,Set<User>> fileToUsers = new HashMap<>();
    public void share(User u, File f) {
        Set<File> files = userToFiles.computeIfAbsent(u, new HashSet<>());
        files.add(f);
        userToFiles.put(u, files);
        Set<User> users = fileToUsers.computeIfAbsent(f, new HashSet<>());
        users.add(u);
        fileToUsers.put(users);
    }
    public Set<File> getFilesSharedBy(User u) {
        return userToFiles.computeIfAbsent(u, Collections.emptySet());
    }
    public Set<User > getFilesSharedBy(File f) {
        return fileToUsers.computeIfAbsent(f, Collections.emptySet());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving on Eran's answer, you could write

```
class User {
       Set<File> sharedFiles;
       boolean hasFile (File f) {
           return sharedFiles.contains(f);
       }
       void shareFile(File f){
           if (!sharedFiles.contains(f))
               sharedFiles.add(f);
               f.shareWith(this);
           }
       }
}

class File {
       Set<User> sharedUsers;
       boolean hasUser (User u) {
           return sharedUsers.contains(u);
       }
       void shareWith(User u){
           if (! sharedUsers.contains(f))
               sharedUsers.add(u);
               u.shareFile(this);
           }
       }
}
```

This way you don't need to implement another method.